# Analytically determining the boundary/boundaries of a multidimensional domain defined by a set of equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I made a post earlier today but it was pretty messy so I am deleting it and making it again by refining my question

I want to know how to analytically and generally determine the boundary or boundaries of an $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ $n>1$ domain if the domain is defined by an equation or set of equations, for example

$f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+...+f_n(x_n)=k$ where $k$ is a constant

and a further set of inequalities

Comment: I think you will have to be more specific on the nature of the analytic functions.